# Using LLVM-C library to disassemble RISC-V instruction but unable to disassemble rem instruction

Tags: llvm, riscv

I am writting a C program to disassemble RISCV instruction using LLVM-C library. It is able to disassemble the basic rv32i instructions but it can't disassemble instruction such as rem in the M extension. How can I make it to work with instructions in riscv extension such as M extension?

Here is my code:

```c
#include <llvm-c/Disassembler.h>
#include <llvm-c/Target.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INST_LEN 129
static LLVMDisasmContextRef dc;
char instbuf[INST_LEN];

void init_disasm() {
    LLVMInitializeAllTargetInfos();
    LLVMInitializeAllTargetMCs();
    LLVMInitializeAllAsmParsers();
    LLVMInitializeAllDisassemblers();
    dc = LLVMCreateDisasm("riscv64", NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
}

char *disasm(uint32_t *inst, uint32_t pc) {
    size_t rc = LLVMDisasmInstruction(dc, (uint8_t*) inst, 4, pc, instbuf, INST_LEN);
    assert(rc); // The assertion will fail if the instruction is rem
    return instbuf;
}
```

The instruction failed to disassemble is 0x033467b3 which is "rem a5,s0,s3"

I searched online but I am not able to find any information about how to add support for riscv extension in LLVM-C library.

Comment: I think the common way to do this kind of thing is to write some code and submit a pull request.